# Android AlertDialog SCrollbar position

Tags: android, scrollbar, android-alertdialog

I am using a ALertDialog to show some results.
i first  display the results in alertdialog and scroll down then press ok.
When showing the next result the scrollbar is in the same position where it was left when  previously shown. How can i bring the scroll bar position to the top of the dialog so that the user can read the new results starting from the top?
PLz reply

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that AlertDialogs scroll if you're just doing `setMessage("Some string")`, so I assume you're adding a View to the custom layout like this:

```
FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.custom);
fl.addView(myView, new LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT));
```

So what if you try `scrollTo` on the View you've added there?

```
myView.scrollTo(0, 0);
```